# using busctl to read sensor values in openbmc

Tags: dbus, openbmc

I'm trying to explore sensor values and signals in openbmc. I can see the available bus names:

```
# busctl |grep Sensor|sed -e 's| .*||'
xyz.openbmc_project.ADCSensor
xyz.openbmc_project.CPUSensor
xyz.openbmc_project.ExitAirTempSensor
xyz.openbmc_project.FanSensor
xyz.openbmc_project.HwmonTempSensor
xyz.openbmc_project.IntrusionSensor
xyz.openbmc_project.IpmbSensor
xyz.openbmc_project.MCUTempSensor
xyz.openbmc_project.PSUSensor
```

But, I can't get any objects out of these. For example:

```
# busctl tree xyz.openbmc_project.HwmonTempSensor
Only root object discovered.
```

Since I'm not getting objects, how do a do a 'busctl introspect'? Sorry if this is obevious. New to dbus...

Answer (score 0):

I am not an authority on either openbmc or DBus, but I will tell you what I can.

When I am not familiar with a bmc platform I will run `busctl tree | less` then search in the output for either `xyz.openbmc_project.Hwmon` or the sensor name I want.
Example:

```
 Service xyz.openbmc_project.Hwmon-3372718265.Hwmon1:
 └─/xyz
   └─/xyz/openbmc_project
     └─/xyz/openbmc_project/sensors
       └─/xyz/openbmc_project/sensors/temperature
         └─/xyz/openbmc_project/sensors/temperature/i2cool_0
```

Then I am able to make my dbus introspect command.

```
busctl introspect xyz.openbmc_project.Hwmon-3372718265.Hwmon1 /xyz/openbmc_project/sensors/temperature/i2cool_0 | less
```

And that brings up the following sections

```
xyz.openbmc_project.Sensor.Value
.MaxValue
.MinValue                                      
.Scale
.Unit
.Value
```

There are many people in the community that work more closely with the dbus sensor interface. But I thought I would share my method.
This is the document I follow when I have a dbus sensor read question.
https://github.com/openbmc/docs/blob/master/architecture/sensor-architecture.md

Comment: not working on my build of openbmc. Maybe a config issue? Thanks for the tips though. I'll keep looking.

Comment: What machine are you targeting? Sensor information typically comes from a file like:
https://github.com/openbmc/openbmc/blob/48b1a11188184b0a63a6e27923bf4a5fb85e2b5b/meta-ibm/meta-romulus/recipes-phosphor/ipmi/romulus-ipmi-sensor-inventory/config.yaml
or is dynamically generated with entity manager.

Comment: It's a local config. I can retry with a qemu build to see if there's anything available.

Answer (score 0):

The process is to first find the sensor.  For that the name of the sensor needs to be known.

```
root@pavilion-evb:~# busctl tree | grep sensor
```

will give you a list.

Then have ObjectMapper tell what Hwmon is monitoring that sensor.

```
root@pavilion-evb:~# dbus-send --system --print-reply  --dest=xyz.openbmc_project.ObjectMapper  /xyz/openbmc_project/object_mapper  xyz.openbmc_project.ObjectMapper.GetObject  string:"\<**SENSOR NAME**>" array:string:
```

example:

```
root@pavilion-evb:~# dbus-send --system --print-reply  --dest=xyz.openbmc_project.ObjectMapper  /xyz/openbmc_project/object_mapper  xyz.openbmc_project.ObjectMapper.GetObject  string:"/xyz/openbmc_project/sensors/voltage/psu4_vin" array:string:
```

returns

> method return time=1663175959.916697 sender=:1.12 ->
> destination=:1.24984 serial=220988 reply_serial=2    array [
> dict entry(
> string "xyz.openbmc_project.Hwmon-3678593568.Hwmon1"
> array [
> string "org.freedesktop.DBus.Introspectable"
> string "org.freedesktop.DBus.Peer"
> string "org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties"
> string "xyz.openbmc_project.Sensor.Threshold.Critical"
> string "xyz.openbmc_project.Sensor.Threshold.Warning"
> string "xyz.openbmc_project.Sensor.Value"
> string "xyz.openbmc_project.State.Decorator.OperationalStatus"
> ]
> )    ]

The key information here is:
xyz.openbmc_project.Hwmon-3678593568.Hwmon1

The use busctl introspect:

```
root@pavilion-evb:~# busctl introspect   xyz.openbmc_project.Hwmon-3678593568.Hwmon1 /xyz/openbmc_project/sensors/voltage/psu4_vin  xyz.openbmc_project.Sensor.Value 
NAME                             TYPE      SIGNATURE RESULT/VALUE                             FLAGS
.MaxValue                        property  d         inf                                      emits-change writable
.MinValue                        property  d         -inf                                     emits-change writable
.Unit                            property  s         "xyz.openbmc_project.Sensor.Value.Unit.\u2026 emits-change writable
.Value                           property  d         208.25                                   emits-change writable
```

Or just the value can be gotten by:

```
root@pavilion-evb:~# busctl get-property  xyz.openbmc_project.Hwmon-3678593568.Hwmon1 /xyz/openbmc_project/sensors/voltage/psu4_vin  xyz.openbmc_project.Sensor.Value Value
d 208.25
```